# d3js Opacity Transition Not Working as Expected

Tags: css, d3.js

I have a group I want to animate form 0 opacity to 1. I've animated it from 1 to 0 fine, but going the other way is strange.

The below code-

```
  showSelection.transition()
    .duration(animate ? 300 : 0)
    .style('opacity', 1)
    .on('end', () => {
      selection.style('pointer-events', 'inherit');
    });
```

Is resulting in `opacity: 9.09815e-08; pointer-events: none;`

I made the opacity value something very high `.style('opacity', 100000000)` and now i'm getting some more like `opacity: 9.25965; pointer-events: none;`

Does anyone know what would cause this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I needed to set the opacity to 0 before animating it to 1.

```
  showSelection.transition()
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .duration(animate ? 300 : 0)
    .style('opacity', 1)
    .on('end', () => {
      selection.style('pointer-events', 'inherit');
    });
```

Comment: Yes elements by default have an opacity of `1`, so without presetting it to `0` you are animating (transitioning) from `1` to `1`...